# How to add numpy to required dependencies in autodoc

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs, autodoc

I get an error when trying to generate the documentation in readthedocs.org, autodoc is failing to import a set of functions with the following error message:

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import function 'open_template' from module 'pypyt'; the following exception was raised:
Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

I'm using the requirements file, so the environment is actually installing numpy. I've tried to mock it, autodoct_mock_imports, autodoct_warningiserro, suppress_warnings, but no has worked.

The conf.py file I use is in the repo below

https://github.com/llulai/pypyt/blob/master/docs/conf.py

Anything I haven't tried yet?

thanks

ps: when I run it locally, it works without any problems

Comment: here is the log of readthedocs.org - https://readthedocs.org/api/v2/build/8508578.txt